# I can not find any document regarding to shared_heap_size

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, aurora

I am new to Postgres and recently I ran one command

```
show all;
```

It returned me a csv file with three columns `name, settings, description`. There are more than 200 results and out of which one result is

```
name : shared_heap_size                      
settings : 1GB                                                               
description : Sets the size of the shared memory segment that is used 
    for Aurora storage metadata and communications.
```

I could not find any document related to this. Can anyone please elaborate?

Output for `select version();`

```
PostgreSQL 9.6.3 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.9.3, 64-bit,
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the description, this is related to Amazon Aurora product, and not PostgreSQL by itself.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.AuroraPostgreSQL.html

> Amazon Aurora PostgreSQL is a fully managed, PostgreSQL-compatible, relational database engine that combines the speed and reliability of high-end commercial databases with the simplicity and cost-effectiveness of open-source databases. Aurora PostgreSQL is a drop-in replacement for PostgreSQL

So Amazon added some settings.

You will need to contact them directly and ask since their documentation does not provide a result when doing a search, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation-guide&searchQuery=shared_heap_size&x=0&y=0&this_doc_product=Amazon+Relational+Database+Service&this_doc_guide=User+Guide&doc_locale=en_us#facet_doc_product=Amazon%20Relational%20Database%20Service&facet_doc_guide=User%20Guide gives *Your search for "shared_heap_size" returned no results.*

Comment: Okay, I will ask to them and get back here.